# How can I set default "color" for bars and boxes (plots) in ggplot2 theme

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I am using theme function to set default colours for dark plots. Everything is all fine except for the lines of bars/boxes for bar and box plots. They are by default grey. I can't seem to find parameter in the theme function to set these to white default in case no "colour" aesthetics are provided.

[image: dark plot]

I have tried the theme function and line parameter, which did not work.

I wonder if there is another way via theme function. I do not want to pass colour via geom_bar or geom_boxplot. I would like to set as a theme.

Comment: Can you give us some data and a the code you used to make this plot? Then we can investigate it easily. As of now, unless someone had already come across this problem, we cannot help you because there is no reproducible example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907040/how-do-i-change-the-outline-colours-of-a-boxplot-with-ggplot